# Does my compiler error really have to do with the quasiquote, or is it something more subtle?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm following the [yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms) example about how to use monadic forms. My getRootR action was taken almost verbatim from the book. I got a compiler error, stripped the quasiquote but still got the error. Below is my error message, the code as it is, followed by what I would like getRootR to look like. Any input as to what the problem might be would be much appreciated.

ghci Rocko.hs

... several "package loading"
 messages pass until ...

Rocko.hs:67:5:

```
Couldn't match type `handler'
               with `GGHandler
                       Scheduler
                       Scheduler
                       (Data.Enumerator.Iteratee Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString IO)'
  `handler' is a rigid type variable bound by
            the type signature for getRootR :: handler RepHtml at Rocko.hs:65:1
Expected type: handler RepHtml
  Actual type: GGHandler
                 Scheduler
                 Scheduler
                 (Data.Enumerator.Iteratee Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString IO)
                 RepHtml
Expected type: handler RepHtml
  Actual type: GHandler Scheduler Scheduler RepHtml
In the return type of a call of `defaultLayout'
In the expression:
  defaultLayout
    (addHtml
       ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . Data.Text.pack)
          "<p>Result: </p>"))
```

Failed, modules loaded: JsonParser.

```
>{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes,
         TemplateHaskell, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
>import Yesod
 import Control.Applicative
 import Control.Monad
 import Data.Text (Text)
 import Data.Time
 import Yesod.Form.Jquery
 import JsonParser

 data Scheduler = Scheduler

 mkYesod "Scheduler" [parseRoutes|
 / RootR GET
 |]

 instance Yesod Scheduler where
    approot _ = ""

 instance RenderMessage Scheduler FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

 instance YesodJquery Scheduler

 data SelectedProduct = MKsp { product :: Text
                             , version :: Text
                             , requestedDate :: Day
                             } deriving Show


 productForm :: Html
             -> Form Scheduler Scheduler (FormResult SelectedProduct, Widget)
 productForm extra = do
    pInfo <- liftIO getUIdata
    let products = Prelude.map productACC $ fst pInfo
        versions = Prelude.map versionsACC $ snd pInfo
        version' = head versions
    (productRes, productView) <- mreq (radioField products) "Placeholder" Nothing
    (versionRes, versionView) <- mreq (selectField version') "Placeholder" Nothing
    (dateRes, dateView) <- mreq (jqueryDayField def
                          { jdsChangeYear = True
                          , jdsYearRange = "2011:2012"
                          }) "Schedule" Nothing
    let selectedRes = MKsp <$> productRes <*> versionRes <*> dateRes
        widget = do
           toWidget [whamlet|
  #{extra}
  <p>
     ^{fvInput productView}
     ^{fvInput versionView}
     ^{fvInput dateView}
     <input type=submit value="aint that some &^*^">
  |]

    return (selectedRes, widget)

 productACC :: ProductNames -> (Text,Text)
 productACC (MKpn pNames) = (pNames,pNames)

 versionsACC :: [ProductVersions] -> [(Text,Text)]
 versionsACC pVersions = Prelude.map vACC' pVersions
                                where vACC' (MKpv pversions') = (pversions', pversions')

 getRootR :: handler RepHtml
 getRootR = do
     ((res, widget), enctype) <- runFormGet productForm
     defaultLayout [whamlet|
 <p>Result:
 |]

 main = return ()
 -- main :: IO ()
 --main = warpDebug 3000 Scheduler `
```

Here's what I would like getRootR to look like for now

```
>getRootR :: Handler RepHtml
 getRootR = do
   ((res, widget), enctype) <- runFormGet productForm
   defaultLayout [whamlet|
  <p>Result: #{show res}
  <form enctype=#{enctype}>
      ^{widget}
  |]
```

Comment: in getRootR :: handler RepHtml .. handler should be Handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is because you have

```
getRootR :: handler RepHtml
```

`Handler` should be with uppercase h.

Comment: Yeah. I suppose this is what happens at the end of a very long day. I knew the answer would be clear in the morning, I didn't know it was going to be one of *those* problems.